# How to implement a NAS at home?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, home-networking, nas

If I wanted to implement a NAS in my house, on which I could keep all my large files and backups, do I need to be on a domain? Ideally I could just plug this into my wireless router and be able to access it as if it was a drive on my PC, like instead of C:\ it'd be D:. Is this possible? If so, can somebody recommend a device that I could use?

Comment: How much space do you want?

Comment: No need for a domain. For the drive letter functionality, you can replicate that with the Map Network Drive function (google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a good one on amazon.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RB1QWW)

It's 1TB with USB or Ethernet connection, and it's basically plug and play.  Power it on and connect it and it shows up as a network drive.

Comment: the image on the amazon site has a wired connection between the router and a desktop machine (server or whatever?). Do I need to have a wired connection to a machine with this? Ideally the device would just be plugged into the router (physically is fine) and tucked away into a corner. All access to the device is done wirelessly.

Comment: There is are 2 options - USB to a pc/mac/whatever, or ethernet to the router.  Plug into the router and it'll show up on all devices on the network as a shared storage volume in the network.

Comment: Glad to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same boat, but my requirements are a bit different:

- NAS (obviously)
- RAID 0,1 (other modes are way more
  expensive)
- Web accessibility/streaming
- Torrent downloads
- Low(er) power consumption

The only one I came up with that has decent reviews is [LinkStation Duo](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822165222)

Pros: seems like they know what they're doing. Good reviews

Cons: bang/buck. When run in mirrored mode, you "lose" half of the capacity.

Comment: Is that really a con? Better to lose half your capacity than all your data.